# python - Get the case-mismatched file names only between two folders in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find the case mismatched file-names between two different folders.

for example, folder1 contains:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

folder2 contains:

```
FILE1.txt
file2.txt
file3.TXT
```

The result should be:

```
FILE1.txt or file1.txt
file3.TXT or file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the filenames in lists, called `a` and `b`. Then you can loop over both and compare the case sensitive file names, if they match, you break the loop, if they don't match but they would match if you change all characters to lower case, you print the file names, i.e.

```
for file1 in a:
    for file2 in b:
        if file1==file2: break
        if file1.lower()==file2.lower():
            print '%s or %s' % (file1,file2)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileNames1 = os.listdir('path1')
fileNames2 = os.listdir('path2')
fileNames1LC = { original.lower(): original for original in fileNames1 }
fileNames2LC = { original.lower(): original for original in fileNames2 }
for lc, original1 in fileNames1LC.iteritems():
    try:
        original2 = fileNames2LC[lc]
    except KeyError:
        # file in path1 found which has no partner in path2
        pass  # do whatever you want to do then
    else:  # found a partner in path2
        if original1 != original2:  # found different capitalisation
            print original2, "or", original1
```

By entering sth at the `pass` statement you can handle files which occur in `path1` but have no partner in `path2`.  If you need to handle files which occur in `path2` and have no partner in `path1`, you have to walk `fileNames2LC` as well.